# Как найти минимальное число и вывести его внутри тега html на JS?

Tags: javascript

Как найти занчения всех `.price` и вывести число в `.min-sum`, используя Javascript?

```html
<div class="parent">
<span>Минимальная стоимость: <b class="min-sum"></b></span>

<div class="product">
<h2>Товар 1</h2>
 <b class="price">100 ₽</b>
</div>

<div class="product">
<h2>Товар 2</h2>
 <b class="price">200 ₽</b>
</div>

<div class="product">
<h2>Товар 3</h2>
 <b class="price">3000 ₽</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм такой

1. используйте функцию для поиска всех объектов price и записи их в переменную `priceObjects`

   ```
    document.querySelectorAll('.price')
   ```
2. чтобы обойти все найденные объекты используйте `for`:

   ```
    for priceObject of priceObjects {
    }
   ```
3. чтобы получить числовое значение используйте свойство узла `.textContent`

   ```
    let priceText = priceObject.textContent;
   ```
4. в тексту у вас буква Р мешает - от нее надо избавиться, например оставить только текст до пробела и перевести его в число или использовать регулярное выражение - как вам хочется
5. выделенную цену сравнивайте с минимальной (изначально минимальная равна к примеру `-1` и тогда надо еще учитывать это значение или присвоить запредельно большое значение)
6. найденное значение опять таки поместить через `document.querySelector('.min-sum')` и `.textContent`